# Getting XY map coordinates on mouse clicks as input variables into a python script

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

This is my first time coding in python, so bear with me. I wrote a script to calculate an analytical solution to find the orientation of a plane based on three points. I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.

```
# Input points
x1 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)) # Point 1
y1 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
z1 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
x2 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)) # Point 2
y2 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))
z2 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6))
x3 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(7)) # Point 3
y3 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(8))
z3 = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(9))

# Plane equation
A = (y1*z2) + (z1*y3) + (y2*z3) - (z2*y3) - (z3*y1) - (z1*y2)
B = (z2*x3) + (z3*x1) + (z1*x2) - (x1*z2) - (z1*x3) - (x2*z3)
C = (x1*y2) + (y1*x3) + (x2*y3) - (y2*x3) - (y3*x1) - (y1*x2)
D = (z1*y2*x3) + (z2*y3*x1) + (z3*y1*x2) - (x1*y2*z3) - (y1*z2*x3) - (z1*x2*y3)
E = np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2 + C**2)

AZ = np.arctan(A/B) * (180/np.pi) # Preliminary azimuth for dip direction
dip = np.arcsin(-np.cos((np.pi/2) + np.arccos(C/E))) * (180/np.pi) # True dip

# Test for quadrant
alpha = A/E
beta = B/E

# Place dip-direction in proper quadrant
if alpha > 0 and beta > 0:
  DD = AZ
elif alpha > 0 and beta < 0:
  DD = 180 + AZ
elif alpha < 0 and beta < 0:
  DD = 180 + AZ
elif alpha < 0 and beta > 0:
  DD = 360 + AZ

# Right-hand rule strike
if DD - 90 < 0:
  RHR = 360 + (DD - 90)
else:
  RHR = DD - 90

# Centroid coordinates
Cx = (x1+x2+x3)/3
Cy = (y1+y2+y3)/3
Cz = (z1+z2+z3)/3

# Insert centroid point
cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)) # Feature class must already exist
row = cursor.newRow()
row.Shape = arcpy.Point(Cx,Cy,Cz)

# Populate table
row.X = Cx
row.Y = Cy
row.Z = Cz
row.DD = DD
row.dip = dip
row.RHR = RHR
cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor, row

# Refresh MXD
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

This works, except that the user has to hover each point and manually enter the coordinates. Ideally, I would like: 
(1) the user initially define the target feature layer in a pop-up menu, and hit OK; 
(2) click on the map to extract the first XY map coordinates; 
(3) pop-up queries the user for the first Z, hit OK; 
(4) click on the map to extract the second XY map coordinates; 
(5) pop-up queries the user for the second Z, hit OK; 
(6) click on the map to extract the last XY map coordinates; 
(7) pop-up queries the user for the last Z, hit OK; then
(8) the script runs to completion.

I found the ESRI tool tutorial that allows the map XY to be displayed on a message box after a mouse-click:

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class MC(object):
    """Implementation for MouseClickSample_addin.MCtool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        message = "Your mouse clicked:" + str(x) + ", " + str(y)
        pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "My Coordinates")
```

I cannot figure out how this Python Add-in can pass the XY variables as input to my script.

Comment: You should try implementing this as a [Python Add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_is_a_Python_add_in/014p00000025000000/).  They allow user interaction.

Comment: @Fezter: The Python Addins I checked out was the Tool, which I got to display the XY coordinates on mouse click, but could do nothing else beyond that (this could be because of my limited knowledge on python); and the Button, which I could not get an XY position on a mouse-click. All the other Addins seem like it didn't fit the kind of UI this script needs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in Layoutview - I get page coordinates not map coordinates - how can I fix this??

Answer (score 9):

You can get the coordinates a mouse click via the `onMouseDownMap()` function of the [Tool Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tool/014p00000027000000/) for Python add-ins.

> The x and y values for **onMouseDownMap** and **onMouseUpMap** represent the map coordinates where the button was pressed or released.

Since you are already creating scripts in Python, it's not much more learning to implement this is an add-in. It's a little bit trickier to debug code, but there is some awesome uses for it, as shown in this video, [Developing Python Add-ins](http://video.esri.com/watch/2288/developing-python-add_dash_ins-for-arcgis-desktop). If my memory serves, there is an example where they grab the coordinates of the map.

-Edit: Actually, it's [this video](http://video.esri.com/watch/1190/developing-arcgis-for-desktop-add_dash_ins-with-python), around the 40 minute mark. I'd recommend watching both though.

Comment: That is more promising that anything I've seen! I'll see if I can figure it out from their tutorial.

Comment: @Jefferson, let us know how it turns out. I'll post some code (it's on my school computer) after my class tomorrow if you are still stuck. There's definitely a learning curve.

Comment: The second video was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is done through a single toolbar, via 8 tools. Much thanks to [Paul](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/19311/paul) for turning me on to those videos. I ended up using 4 combo boxes for text input, 3 tools to store the XY's, and a push button to implement the script.

[image: Toolbar]

```
import numpy as np
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class Calculate(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.calculatebtn (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False

    def onClick(self):
        # Input points
        x1 = float(xy1tool.x1) # Point 1
        y1 = float(xy1tool.y1)
        z1 = float(z1cmb.text)
        x2 = float(xy2tool.x2) # Point 2
        y2 = float(xy2tool.y2)
        z2 = float(z2cmb.text)
        x3 = float(xy3tool.x3) # Point 3
        y3 = float(xy3tool.y3)
        z3 = float(z3cmb.text)

        # Plane equation
        A = (y1*z2) + (z1*y3) + (y2*z3) - (z2*y3) - (z3*y1) - (z1*y2)
        B = (z2*x3) + (z3*x1) + (z1*x2) - (x1*z2) - (z1*x3) - (x2*z3)
        C = (x1*y2) + (y1*x3) + (x2*y3) - (y2*x3) - (y3*x1) - (y1*x2)
        D = (z1*y2*x3) + (z2*y3*x1) + (z3*y1*x2) - (x1*y2*z3) - (y1*z2*x3) - (z1*x2*y3)
        E = np.sqrt(A**2 + B**2 + C**2)

        AZ = np.arctan(A/B) * (180/np.pi) # Preliminary azimuth for dip trend
        dip = np.arcsin(-np.cos((np.pi/2) + np.arccos(C/E))) * (180/np.pi) # True dip

        # Test for quadrant
        alpha = A/E
        beta = B/E

        # Place dip-direction in proper quadrant
        if alpha > 0 and beta > 0:
          DD = AZ
        elif alpha > 0 and beta < 0:
          DD = 180 + AZ
        elif alpha < 0 and beta < 0:
          DD = 180 + AZ
        elif alpha < 0 and beta > 0:
          DD = 360 + AZ

        # Right-hand rule strike
        if DD - 90 < 0:
          RHR = 360 + (DD - 90)
        else:
          RHR = DD - 90

        # Centroid coordinates
        Cx = (x1+x2+x3)/3
        Cy = (y1+y2+y3)/3
        Cz = (z1+z2+z3)/3

        # Insert centroid point
        cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(pointlayercmb.layername) # Feature class must already exist
        row = cursor.newRow()
        row.Shape = arcpy.Point(Cx,Cy,Cz)

        # Populate table
        row.X = Cx
        row.Y = Cy
        row.Z = Cz
        row.DD = DD
        row.dip = dip
        row.RHR = RHR
        cursor.insertRow(row)
        del cursor, row

        # Refresh MXD
        arcpy.RefreshTOC()
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

        # Refresh elevations
        z1cmb.refresh()
        z2cmb.refresh()
        z3cmb.refresh()

class Elevation1(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.z1cmb (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWW'
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def refresh(self):
        self.value = " "

class Elevation2(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.z2cmb (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWW'
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def refresh(self):
        self.value = " "

class Elevation3(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.z3cmb (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWW'
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        self.text = text
    def refresh(self):
        self.value = " "

class PointLayer(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.pointlayercmb (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.editable = False
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWWWWW'
        self.mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('Current')
        layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(self.mxd)
        for layer in layers:
            pointlayercmb.items.append(layer.name)
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        self.layername = selection

class SelectPoint1(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.xy1tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 3
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        self.x1 = x
        self.y1 = y
        print "Point 1: " + str(x) + ", " + str(y)

class SelectPoint2(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.xy2tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 3
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        self.x2 = x
        self.y2 = y
        print "Point 2: " + str(x) + ", " + str(y)

class SelectPoint3(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.xy3tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.cursor = 3
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        self.x3 = x
        self.y3 = y
        print "Point 3: " + str(self.x3) + ", " + str(y)

class UpdateLayers(object):
    """Implementation for ThreePointProblem_addin.layersext (Extension)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # For performance considerations, please remove all unused methods in this class.
        self.enabled = True
    def itemAdded(self, new_item):
        pointlayercmb.items.append(new_item.name)
        pointlayercmb.refresh()
    def itemDeleted(self, deleted_item):
        pointlayercmb.items.remove(deleted_item.name)
        pointlayercmb.refresh()
```